# "Where" in careers' search seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, feedback

Let's say I want to find a company in **Ontario, Canada**.
Ok, I navigate to company pages and type `ON, Canada` to `Where` in search:

> [image: ontario search]

but there are no companies in there. So why if I type just `Canada` it finds companies in ontario; and if I type specific area (ON, CA)  it doesn't find anything ?

> [image: canada search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently in the process of making changes to our search products in order to improve the results, and geographical filtering is one of the first features which is likely to see improvements in the not too distant future. In the meantime, we are rolling out some incremental changes, including one just a few minutes ago. If you search for company pages in Ontario, Canada, the results will now be much closer to what you were expecting to see.

We definitely appreciate reports like this which help us identify areas which need more immediate attention. Thanks, and feel free to post anything like this you may come across in the future.